# Calculate and put number of days between points on graph

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am looking to see distribution of certain events by date. I need to see time in days between each point on the graph. How do i do that?

[image]

```
date_time=[datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d') for date_string in date_time]

dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(date_time)

plt.scatter(date_time, [5]*len(dates))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use [`text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html?highlight=text#module-matplotlib.text) to place labels, like in [these examples](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#text_labels_and_annotations).

Comment: @berna1111 thanx. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer thanx to @berna1111

[image]

```
    plt.scatter(date_time, [5]*len(date_time))
s = date_time[0]
p=0
for i in date_time[1:]:
    l = (i - s).days
    #print(i , '-', s, '=', l)
    s=date_time[date_time.index(i)]
    if l > 30:
        plt.text(i,5.001,l)
        plt.text(i,4.999-p,i.date())
        p+=0.001
        if p == 0.002:
            p = 0
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```